# Get event handler of MenuItem programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling, menuitem

I defined this menu item in xaml:

```
<MenuItem 
   Header="header of item"  
   Click="eventhandler_of_item" 
   Name="nameofitem"/>
```

Now I would like get the event handler of the click event programmatically.
Getting the header is easy:

```
string header = nameofitem.Header.ToString();
```

But getting the click event handler seems to be a bit more tricky.
Could anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's messy, i would recommend you use [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx), they can be passed around easily.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think, that this is possible. You only can add or remove an event-handler (register and unregister).
As far as I know, there is no possibility to iterate through the attached handlers (I wrote iterate, because potentially there can be more than one handler attached to an event).

*For CLR-events, I remember that I have seen once a solution based on reflection.*

As H.B. stated (+1), use Commands, this are "normal" types and can be used as you desire...